# How do I shelve my changes of one particular folder in Git repository?

Tags: git, github, tfs, shelve

Following is the exact scenario:

Master branch in git repository is having two folders:

- Project A
- Project B

I have done some major changes in Project B, whereas Project A is completely untouched.
Now, I dont want to commit and push the changes in Project B at this stage, because it is waiting for the review, and there may be some revisions which may take upto a few weeks. At the same time, I dont want to keep those changes on local just to make sure that I dont lose those changes on any catastrophic event.

As I have done the changes directly in Master branch, I want to shelve those changes and will commit them later on (may be after a month). No other developer is working on that project, so I am least bothered at the time of merging.

Could anyone please suggest how can I shelve those changes, or create a private branch of those changes to merge them with the master later on?

Any help on this will be much appreciated. Thank you.

P.S. - Sorry if this looked like a basic question, but I am a TFS guy, so finding it a bit difficult to get used to with Git. There I could simply do this in one or two steps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is a *project* based version control system.  This means that when you commit your work in Git, you generally commit *every* file in the repository.  So there is no distinction between your two folders with regard to this.  Note that this differs from a VCS tool like Perforce or CVS, where you could version just one of these two folders.

With regard to your problem, perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to just create a feature branch from your current work.  You can try the following:

```
# git checkout yourBranch if not already there
git checkout -b my_project_b            # create a new branch from this point
git add .                               # add your files changed
git commit -m 'Project B latest work'   # commit your work
```

Now you can push your new branch with Project B changes to the remote via

```
git push origin my_project_b
```

When it comes time to use this work, simply merge `my_project_b` into the destination branch.

Comment: Thanks, This is a solution for the scenario I am having, also with this, I have got more idea about feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim has given a good solution. I'd like to share a tricky but not that useful one.

Now you have made some changes in Project B. Let's say the folder name is PB.

```
git add .
git commit
git ls-tree HEAD | grep PB
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

The expected output of `ls-tree` is something like
`040000 tree 765b32c65d38f....    PB`

This is a tree object, a snapshot of PB. We can make a tag for it.

```
git tag -m "tag of PB tree" tree_PB 765b32c65d38f
```

The tag `tree_PB` can be pushed or fetched.

```
git init tmp_PB
cd tmp_PB
git fetch <remote> tree_PB
git read-tree FETCH_HEAD -u --reset
```

The files in PB are extracted from the tree object into the current folder and are staged. You can copy them to the original repo.